# get file changes when FileWatcher does not fire

Tags: c#, .net

I have a a program (matrkion Data Manager to be exact) that write to a log file up to s curtain size then begins overwriting the log from the beginning. Not exactly ideal for debugging and event logging. So I am trying to write a C# program to establish a FileWatcher object so when the log is written to I can get the changes and save them off. This way I can see the entire log contents. The issue is the FileWatcher Change event is never thrown so can know when the log is changed. The only thing that is thrown is a FileSizeChange flag when the log is not filled, which it is always filled. Is there another way I can go about this?

Comment: Clearly FSW is of no use to you.  Nothing left but to poll with a timer.

Comment: Thats what I was afarid of, i didnt know if there was a way i could get when the disk was written to in the area of the log but.... a timer it is!

Comment: What notify filters have you tried?  Maybe include some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go ahead and use a timer to poll the log every x seconds. Not efficient but it works.